# Update a single column based on multiple conditions in an expression

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to update all the values in a single column. The column currently contains only NULL values.

There are two columns in the table to be updated and the table the new data should be taken from that need to match for the update to take place.

After looking up the problem, it does not seem to have been mentioned before in the way it needs to be solved here.

The code I have come up with so far is (and does not work a bit):

```
UPDATE ANSWER_PATTERN AS outer
SET outer.ANSWER_DURATION = 
(
    SELECT inner.ANSWER_DURATION
    FROM PREP_ANSWER_DURATION AS inner
    WHERE (inner.TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID,
           inner.STUDENT_EXT_ID) = 
          (outer.TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID,
           outer.STUDENT_EXT_ID)
);
```

So, how can I get the values from table2 in the column ANSWER_DURATION into table1, column ANSWER_DURATION, provided the TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID and STUDENT_EXT_ID columns both match?

I would be glad for any help provided. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do that:

```
UPDATE  outer, inner
SET    outer.ANSWER_DURATION = inner.ANSWER_DURATION
WHERE   inner.TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID=outer.TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID AND 
       inner.STUDENT_EXT_ID=outer.STUDENT_EXT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this achieves what you're looking for.  My experience with your database flavor is nonexistent, but this is how I would approach the problem using PostgreSQL.

```
UPDATE ANSWER_PATTERN t1
SET ANSWER_DURATION = t2.ANSWER_DURATION
FROM PREP_ANSWER_DURATION t2
WHERE t2.TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID = t1.TEST_ITEM_EXT_ID 
  AND t2.STUDENT_EXT_ID = t1.STUDENT_EXT_ID;
```

Comment: It helped to find a solution, thank you. Would not work like this in SQL, though, since the first "ANSWER_DURATION" had no qualifier and the language structure is a bit different.